# Dua to be protected from being answerable/subjugated to a Kaafir?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, dua

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

I'm searching for a dua that our Beloved Prophet (Saw) made, IF any, regarding protection by Allah Swt from the humiliation or subjugation of the kaafir. Can you please help me find it?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of this.

> Allah burdens not a person beyond his scope. He gets reward for that (good) which he has earned, and he is punished for that (evil) which he has earned. "***Our Lord! Punish us not if we forget or fall into error, our Lord! Lay not on us a burden like that which You did lay on those before us (Jews and Christians); our Lord! Put not on us a burden greater than we have strength to bear. Pardon us and grant us Forgiveness. Have mercy on us. You are our Maula (Patron, Suppor-ter and Protector, etc.) and give us victory over the disbelieving people.***" ([Qur'an 2:286](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=2&verse=286))